# How to extend the border to full width whilst the body is set at 77%

Tags: html, css

I have set all elements to be middle of the page fitting at 77%. Using this code here:

```
body{
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 77%;
 font-family: arial;
}
```

I have added a bottom border with a blue colour and it is also at width of 77%.

How can I extend the blue border to go all the way to fit the page? But keep all other elements at 77%?

I have attached a snippet, I know it doesn't work great, but I am currently practicing on my knowledge of borders, and this is what I have come across to.

I just need the blue line to run across the whole page.

```css
body{
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 width: 77%;
 font-family: arial;
}
#head{
 border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
 overflow: hidden
}

.container{
 width: 100%;
}

#head ul{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 float: right;
 padding-bottom: 10px;

}
#head ul li{
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 20px;
 padding-left: 20px;

}
#head a{
 text-decoration: none;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

#head header{
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 30px;
 margin-top: 10px;
}

#head .container header{
 color: #0D1D6B;
 text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
}

#head .container span{
 color: #fff; 
 text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>practise</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

 <section id="head">
  <div class="container">
   <header>Holiday <span>resort</span></header>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
   </ul>

  </div>

 </section>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Typically this would be done with a full-width header that has a 77% width container inside of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way to do it is to use parent div, Make the `width` of the parent 100% and set the `border` for the parent, then set the `width` of `#head` to 100%. you can center the `#head` by adding `margin: auto`

### Here is the code

```css
    body{
     margin: auto;
     padding: 0;
     font-family: arial;
    }

    .wrapper{   
      width: 100%;
       border-bottom: 2px solid blue;

    }
    #head{
      width: 77%;
      overflow: hidden;
      margin: auto;  
    }

    .container{
     width: 100%;
    }

    #head ul{
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     float: right;
     padding-bottom: 10px;

    }
    #head ul li{
     list-style: none;
     display: inline-block;
     font-size: 20px;
     padding-left: 20px;

    }
    #head a{
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
    }

    #head header{
     text-transform: uppercase;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 30px;
     margin-top: 10px;
    }

    #head .container header{
     color: #0D1D6B;
     text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
    }

    #head .container span{
     color: #fff; 
     text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title>practise</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="wrapper">
     <section id="head">
      <div class="container">
       <header>Holiday <span>resort</span></header>
       <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
       </ul>

      </div>

     </section>
      </div>



    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this would be done with a full-width header that has a 77% width container inside of it. I've added `.container` elements to the header, main content region, and footer of the page.

I've also updated to use flexbox for the menu items.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
}

nav {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
}

footer {
  border-top: 2px solid blue;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 77%;
}

.primary-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.primary-nav li {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.primary-nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.brand,
.brand span {
  text-shadow: 1px 0 0 #000, 0 -1px 0 #000, 0 1px 0 #000, -1px 0 0 #000;
}

.brand {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: #0D1D6B;
}

.brand span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav>
      <span class="brand">Holiday <span>resort</span></span>
      <ul class="primary-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Services</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>

<main>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor.
    </p>
  </div>
</main>

<footer>
  <div class="container">
    Footer
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following css to the `#head`

```
#head{
  width: calc(100% + 23%);
  border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-left: -11.5%;
}
```

Comment: can you explain what the calc inside width is please?

Comment: since the body is only 77% we are adding the remaining 23% to the `#head` element in order to reach the 100%. Then we offset the left margin half of the 23% so the `#head` is centered on the page. Also the `100%` in the `#head` really equates to `77%` since its parent - the body - is only `77%`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width to 100% and then add `padding` of 11.5% on each side of the `div`, resulting in the `div` being 77% of the page. Since padding is inside the `div`, the border will extend till the end of the page, unlike if you set `margin` to 11.5%, since `margin` is on the outside of the `div`.

```
body{  
    width: 100%;
    font-family: arial;
    padding-right: 11.5%;
    padding-left: 11.5%;
    border-bottom: solid blue 2px;
}
```